# How do I use the Checkbox with Java + Spring in Thymeleaf/HTML?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, checkbox, thymeleaf

How do I receive either true or false from an checkbox in html with Thymeleaf over to my controller, so I can take the value either true or false and save in my DB. So far I receive these errors:

1. ```
   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException:
   An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/normal/start-dag.html]")
   ```
2. ```
   Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException:
   Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputCheckboxFieldTagProcessor' (template: "normal/start-dag" - line 24, col 44)
   ```
3. ```
   Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException:
   Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputCheckboxFieldTagProcessor' (template: "normal/start-dag" - line 24, col 44)
   ```
4. ```
   2018-07-17 09:05:16.097 ERROR 6713 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed;
   nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/normal/start-dag.html]")] with root cause
   ```
5. ```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'goodNightOfSleep' available as request attribute
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:153) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
   ```

My html looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <input type="checkbox" th:path="goodNightOfSleep">
        <label th:for="${#ids.next('goodNightOfSleep')}" th:text="#{StartDay.goodNightOfSleep}">Kan du huske hvad du drømte?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{goodNightOfSleep}"/>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And my Controller:

```
// Start Day
@GetMapping("/normal/start-dag")
public  String opretGoal() {
    return "normal/start-dag";
}

@PostMapping("/normal/start-dag")
public String opretGoal(@ModelAttribute StartDay startDay, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "/normal/menu";
    }
    startDayService.createGoalOfTheDay(startDay);

    return "normal/menu";
}
```

My StartDay.java class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "start_day")
public class StartDay {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "age_in_days", nullable = true)
    private int ageInDays;
    @Column(name = "day_created", nullable = true)
    private String dayCreated;
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = true)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "dream_remembered", nullable = true)
    private boolean dreamRemembered;
    @Column(name = "nightmare", nullable = true)
    private boolean nightmare;
    @Column(name = "waking_time", nullable = true)
    private int wakingTime;
    @Column(name = "good_night_of_sleep", nullable = true)
    private boolean goodNightOfSleep;
```

Any help appreciated :)

UPDATE #1

So I just tried to move the second th:field from the html, so it looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <input type="checkbox" th:path="goodNightOfSleep">
        <label th:for="${#ids.next('goodNightOfSleep')}" th:text="#{StartDay.goodNightOfSleep}">Kan du huske hvad du drømte?</label>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And that makes me actually able to land on the page, but my checkbox looks like this, and doesn't return a value: [image]

Comment: I think there is a slash missing at the end of your <input .../> tag.
<input type="checkbox" th:path="goodNightOfSleep" />

Comment: @pDer666: That's valid html5 syntax.

Comment: Just added it - nothing changed, but appreciated :)

Comment: Ok, should there be a checkbox for yes and a checkbox for no? At the moment your combination of th:path in the first and th:field in the second input field doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Mango: Only add the ending slash if you are not using html5. Html5 doesn't specify the closing slash for input fields.

Comment: @Flocke No there should only be one checkbox with the value yes, and if clicked it should return true and if not just return false :)

Comment: @Flocke Oh alright, thank you! :)

Comment: A TemplateProcessingException says that is something wrong in html. the template processor of thymeleaf is very strict with closing slashes in html tags neither it is html5 or not

Comment: @pDer666 That's not the point. I'm using thymleaf with html5 a lot and this isn't a issue. Thymeleaf doesn't force invalid HTML.

Comment: @Mango: Could you please post the StartDay-class (no need to show getter/setter). ... You could also replace th:path with a simple name attribute. There is no need for th:path.

Comment: @Flocke I have added my StartDay Class, and I'll try to replace th:path :)

Comment: @Mongo: I write a small sample. Wait a few minutes (I'm at work and my boss is bitchy about private-stuff at work)

Comment: @Flocke - No rush! It's really appreciated, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Controller methods:

```
@GetMapping("/normal/start-dag")
public String opretGoal(Model model) {
    ...
    StartDay startDay = .... // e.g. new StartDay();
    model.addAttribute("startDay", startDay);
    ...
    return "normal/start-dag";
}

@PostMapping("/normal/start-dag")
public String opretGoal(@Valid StartDay startDay, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model)
{
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        // log and/or handle errors
    }
    else {
        // your logic goes here
        startDayService.createGoalOfTheDay(startDay);
    }
    return "/normal/menu";
}
```

## Template snippet:

```
<form action="... or use th:action" method="post" th:object="${startDay}">
    ...
    <input type="checkbox" name="goodNightOfSleep">
    ...
</form>
```

You could also use th:field for the goodNightOfSleep-Input but it works like writen above. Thymeleaf match the field by name to the object defined in the form-element. If you check the box the value will be true else it will be false.

The point is to 1.) add the object to the model and 2.) receive the object as a input parameter.

Warning: The code is writen to the editor without testing it. Maybe there are typos.

Comment: Okay, so this totally fixed everything, now I just need to make my sql work with the database. Thank you for the help, really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try returning a `ModelAndView` instead of your `String`, and adding your `StartDay` as Model attribute as described [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html)?

e.g.

```
@GetMapping("/normal/start-dag")
public ModelAndView opretGoal(){

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("normal/start-dag");
    mav.addObject("StartDay", new StartDay());
    return mav;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that for showing an objects values? Im just adding the StartDay through my @ModelAttribute, and then im supposed to fill the values through my form and just return an object of startDay, which is then saved to my DB. I was told the use of RequestMapping is an old way of working with Spring, since we got GetMapping and PostMapping. Or am I wrong? - Thanks for your time!

Comment: oh, that has nothing to do with get/postmapping, get/postmapping is just a shorter way of writing requestmapping(method=GET)/requestmapping(method=POST)

Comment: Oh okay! I just tried your code and it doesn't work, because my `StartDayService.createGoalOfTheDay(startDay)); ` is returning void, so it wont let me. Its pure sql (INSERT INTO).

Comment: ah ok, is the "GET" returning this Exception or your "POST"? probably you have to add the model to your "GET" - updated my answer to match

Comment: So yeah, this worked - now it return either true or false (if checked or unchecked), but i still got the label problem, showing something totally different than supposed.

Answer (score 0):

> 5. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'goodNightOfSleep' available as request attribute
>      at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:153) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>      at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]

Error No 5 is because thymeleaf is not able to find "goodNightOfSleep" attribute.

Try passing StartDay object in the model attribute of get request.

```
@GetMapping("/normal/start-dag")
public  String opretGoal(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("startDay", new startDay());
    return "normal/start-dag";
}
```

and make sure startDay "th:object" is defined in the UI.

```
<form th:action="@{normal/start-dag}" th:object="${startDay}" method="post">
```

Comment: Okay, so this worked - I do now receive either true or false, but my checkbox still shows the incorrect text from the label. Do you know how to fix this?